# rich text: changing the bullet character?

Tags: crystal-reports, richtext

because of problems with the bullets in crystal report (they simply dont appear), i want to change the bullet sign to something similiar like ' * ' or '●'.

the rtf specification (http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm#Heading33) says for \pnlvlblt

> Bulleted paragraph (corresponds to
>   level 11). The actual character used
>   for the bullet is stored in the
>   \pntxtb group.

and for \pntxtb

> '{' \pntxtb #PCDATA'}'

```
#PCDATA means text without control words.
```

anyone here knows how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

To store bulleted text in MySQL and show in crystal report with C#
-set data type as blob in MySQL table
-to save, use rich textbox in c# and in sql statement, set the parameter's data type as blob

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Description", MySqlDbType.Blob));
```

-to retrieve, I use parameter field for crystal report and change the string got from select statement to unicode

```
byte[] myByte = (byte[])dtResult.Rows[0]["rdescription"];
string res = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myByte, 0, myByte.Length);
```

-Set Text Interpretation to RTF Text for that parameter field.

It works for me.